# Streamer Glow Effect: Star Trek New Generation - S.7 E.11

Tags: after-effects, special-effects, visual-effects

I was watching this episode and was amazed by the effect that they did to the streamers.

How would they pull this off?

I couldn't capture a picture of this but ill try to explain it.
The streamers glow but they are also behind, in front and on the characters. There is no glowing on anything else. The streamers are real objects that have been glowed.

Thanks.

Comment: It might help you get answers if you can illustrate this effect with an image, screengrab, anything.

Comment: Apologizes for the delay, I can probably explain this as an glow effect on the objects that they threw. But what threw me off was the fact that the objects flew behind the actors and the effect didn't show on anything else.

I can probably justify this now with the fact that the colours on the streamers where high vis or something reflective to light.